# Pickling issue in Django management command but works in regular Python environment

Tags: python-3.x, django, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am facing a pickling issue specifically when using the dfi.export() function within a Django management command, while the same code works without any issues in a regular Python environment.

I am using Django version 2.2.4 and Python version 3.10.0 The code involves exporting a Pandas DataFrame to an image file using the dfi.export() function from the dataframe_image library. The goal is to generate an image file from the DataFrame within the Django management command.

```
from decimal import Decimal
import dataframe_image as dfi
import pandas as pd

def color_negative_red(val):
    color = 'red' if val < 0 else 'green'
    return 'color: %s' % color


futures_risk_table_1={'PNL ITD': {'BTCUSDT': Decimal('-366.91850000'),
  'ETHUSDT': Decimal('20.11800000'),
  'TOTAL': Decimal('-241.39039746')},
 'FUNDING ITD': {'BTCUSDT': Decimal('285.87113447'),
  'ETHUSDT': Decimal('11.23925312'),
  'TOTAL': Decimal('230.66567605')},
 'DELTA VOLUME ITD': {'BTCUSDT': Decimal('11413146.44950000'),
  'ETHUSDT': Decimal('3739417.96300000'),
  'TOTAL': Decimal('16904364.71747007')},
 'HEDGE VOLUME ITD': {'BTCUSDT': Decimal('5858487.37460000'),
  'ETHUSDT': Decimal('2208062.55358281'),
  'TOTAL': Decimal('9812329.10964750')},
 'GROSS OI': {'BTCUSDT': 1142375.5,
  'ETHUSDT': 34665.484173792,
  'TOTAL': 1507336.3651526954},
 'DEFICIT': {'BTCUSDT': 4126.2,
  'ETHUSDT': 6105.2643768768,
  'TOTAL': 14643.812931051634},
 'PNL 4HR': {'BTCUSDT': Decimal('-110.42400000'),
  'ETHUSDT': Decimal('-19.04450000'),
  'TOTAL': Decimal('-58.85838895')},
 'FUNDING 4HR': {'BTCUSDT': Decimal('51.78039448'),
  'ETHUSDT': Decimal('-0.15025893'),
  'TOTAL': Decimal('35.63325078')},
 'DELTA VOLUME 4HR': {'BTCUSDT': Decimal('2554914.73350000'),
  'ETHUSDT': Decimal('1032545.61450000'),
  'TOTAL': Decimal('3892830.05291726')},
 'HEDGE VOLUME 4HR': {'BTCUSDT': Decimal('1393409.78960000'),
  'ETHUSDT': Decimal('332477.41883101'),
  'TOTAL': Decimal('2029616.07723308')}}


futures_risk_table_1=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(futures_risk_table_1)
print(type(futures_risk_table_1))
futures_risk_table_1_styler = futures_risk_table_1.style.applymap(color_negative_red).set_caption("Futures Risk Monitor").format("{:20,.0f}").set_properties(
        subset=pd.IndexSlice[futures_risk_table_1.index[-1], :],
        **{'background-color': 'lightblue'}
        )
futures_risk_table_1_styler
dfi.export(futures_risk_table_1_styler,"files/images/futures_risk_table_1_styler.png")
```

When I run this code within the Django management command, I encounter the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.TextIOWrapper' object
```

The code using django command is

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self,*args,**kwargs):
            futures_risk_table_1={'PNL ITD': {'BTCUSDT': Decimal('-366.91850000'),
                    'ETHUSDT': Decimal('20.11800000'),
                    'TOTAL': Decimal('-241.39039746')},
                    'FUNDING ITD': {'BTCUSDT': Decimal('285.87113447'),
                    'ETHUSDT': Decimal('11.23925312'),
                    'TOTAL': Decimal('230.66567605')},
                    'DELTA VOLUME ITD': {'BTCUSDT': Decimal('11413146.44950000'),
                    'ETHUSDT': Decimal('3739417.96300000'),
                    'TOTAL': Decimal('16904364.71747007')},
                    'HEDGE VOLUME ITD': {'BTCUSDT': Decimal('5858487.37460000'),
                    'ETHUSDT': Decimal('2208062.55358281'),
                    'TOTAL': Decimal('9812329.10964750')},
                    'GROSS OI': {'BTCUSDT': 1142375.5,
                    'ETHUSDT': 34665.484173792,
                    'TOTAL': 1507336.3651526954},
                    'DEFICIT': {'BTCUSDT': 4126.2,
                    'ETHUSDT': 6105.2643768768,
                    'TOTAL': 14643.812931051634},
                    'PNL 4HR': {'BTCUSDT': Decimal('-110.42400000'),
                    'ETHUSDT': Decimal('-19.04450000'),
                    'TOTAL': Decimal('-58.85838895')},
                    'FUNDING 4HR': {'BTCUSDT': Decimal('51.78039448'),
                    'ETHUSDT': Decimal('-0.15025893'),
                    'TOTAL': Decimal('35.63325078')},
                    'DELTA VOLUME 4HR': {'BTCUSDT': Decimal('2554914.73350000'),
                    'ETHUSDT': Decimal('1032545.61450000'),
                    'TOTAL': Decimal('3892830.05291726')},
                    'HEDGE VOLUME 4HR': {'BTCUSDT': Decimal('1393409.78960000'),
                    'ETHUSDT': Decimal('332477.41883101'),
                    'TOTAL': Decimal('2029616.07723308')}}
            
            futures_risk_table_2={'PNL BOTTOM 2': {'Contract-1': 'BTCUSDT(-408)',
                            'Contract-2': 'XRPUSDT(-101)'},
                            'FUNDING BOTTOM 2': {'Contract-1': 'LDOUSDT(-14)',
                            'Contract-2': 'XRPUSDT(-12)'},
                            'POSITION DEFICIT TOP 2': {'Contract-1': 'ETHUSDT (6105)',
                            'Contract-2': 'BTCUSDT (4126)'},
                            'VOLUME DIFFERANCE TOP 2': {'Contract-1': 'BTCUSDT(7,867,622)',
                            'Contract-2': 'ETHUSDT(1,900,193)'},
                            'VOLUME DIFFERANCE BOTTOM 2': {'Contract-1': 'MATICUSDT(-654)',
                            'Contract-2': 'NEARUSDT(-124)'}}
            
            futures_risk_table_1=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(futures_risk_table_1)
            futures_risk_table_2=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(futures_risk_table_2)
            futures_risk_table_1_styler = futures_risk_table_1.style.applymap(self.color_negative_red).set_caption("Futures Risk Monitor").format("{:20,.0f}").set_properties(
                    subset=pd.IndexSlice[futures_risk_table_1.index[-1], :],
                    **{'background-color': 'lightblue'}
                    )


            dfi.export(futures_risk_table_1,'files/images/futures_risk_table_1.png')
            dfi.export(futures_risk_table_2,'files/images/futures_risk_table_2.png')
```

What could be causing this pickling issue specifically within the Django management command? Is there any difference in the pickling behavior or limitations within the Django framework that I need to consider? How can I resolve this issue and successfully export the DataFrame as an image within the Django management command?

NOTE: THIS WAS WORKING GOOD IN DJANGO IN PYTHON 3.7 VERSION

Answer (score 0):

Its because of django version change. Updating django fixed.